# How to type vue Component in props

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-props

```
<template>
  <v-dialog
    width="auto"
    v-model="isShown"
    transition="dialog-bottom-transition"
  >
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title v-if="title"> {{ title }}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <component v-if="checkText()" :is="text"></component>
        <span v-else>{{ text }}</span>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-card-actions>
        //
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, computed } from "vue";

const params = defineProps<{
  show: boolean;
  title?: string;
  text: string | object;
  confirmButtonText?: string;
  closeButtonText: string;
}>();
const emit = defineEmits(["closeWindow", "confirmOperation"]);

const isShown = computed({
  get() {
    return params.show;
  },
  set(newValue) {
    emit("closeWindow");
  },
});

function checkText() {
  return typeof params.text !== "string";
}
</script>
```

I want to pass into my reusable modal window props string or vue Component, but i dont know how to type my prop "text" correct.

I use object and it works but i want to use strong typing. P.S. v-dialog, v-card etc are vuetify components.

Comment: To pass Vue components you should better use `slots`, not `props`.

Comment: @Tolbxela yeah, thx. I`ve read about slot and my problem became not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a component and rendering it using Vue's h function:

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
const FieldRender = defineComponent({
  name: 'FieldRender',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: [String, Number, Object] as PropType<string | number | VNode | Component>,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    return () => {
      if (typeof props.value === 'string' || typeof props.value === 'number')
        return props.value
      return props.value ? h(props.value) : null
    }
  },
})
```

To use it, you can do the following:

```html
<template>
  <FieldRender :value="text" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { Component, VNode } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps<{
  text?: Component | number | string
}>()
</script>
```

This code is implemented in [@unoverlays/vue](https://github.com/hairyf/unoverlays/tree/master/packages/vue), so you can also install @unoverlays/vue and use it directly:

```bash
pnpm i @unoverlays/vue
```

```html
<template>
  <FieldRender :value="text" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { FieldRender } from '@unoverlays/vue'
import { Component, VNode } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps<{
  text?: string | number | VNode | Component
}>()
</script>
```

If you want to validate props, you can use the validator of props.